# Reducing the execution time

Tags: python, string, loops, time-complexity, execution-time

Following is my code which returns the total number of substrings in which-

- all the characters are the same, eg: 'aaaa'
- all the characters are same except the middle one, eg: 'aadaa'

given the string , s = 'mnonopoo' we have the following special substrings: { 'm', 'n', 'o', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'o', 'o', 'oo', 'non', 'ono', 'opo' }
You just have to return the total number of that special substrings. In this case, it is 12.

```
def palin(x):
    if x==x[::-1]:
        if len(set(x))==1 or len(set(x))==2:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
    
def special_string(string):
    result=[]
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(string)+1):
            r= string[i:j]
            if palin(r):
                result.append(r)
    return len(result)
```

My code works fine with smaller inputs but gets terminated for large inputs. Please help me to improve my code.

Comment: Your first function doesn't do what you described: it would return `True` for 'dadad'.

Comment: You're supposed to figure this out yourself, that's the point of the exercise... But I think maybe you could use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)